# How to split a Sequence in scala

Tags: scala

I'm using play framework with Scala and I want to split a `Seq[String]` into subsequence.

I return `Seq[String]` from a SQL Query which contains colors and season, it look like that:

> spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blu

The seasons and colours are separated by a comma, and I want to split that sequence to get 2 subsequences, one with the seasons and other with colors.

I've tried with:

```
val subsequence=sequecne.split(",")
```

But it doesn't work and return that error: value split is not a member of `Seq[String]`

So what can I do?

Comment: This question is unclear to me, and apparently to others as well as you seem unsatisfied with given solution. You should provide what exactly you have and what you want to get. For example: given a seq `val seq: Seq[String] = Seq("spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blu")` you want to get `Seq(Seq("spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"), Seq("red", "green", "blu")`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `sequence` is like a sequence containing one string:

```
val sequence = Seq("spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blu")
val split = sequence.flatMap(_.split(","))
// => split: Seq[String] = List(spring; summer; autumn; winter, " red; green; blu")
```

Comment: I try it but when I do `println(split)` it write:
List:(spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blue)

And me I want 2 subsequence to use it separatly

Comment: Ah, so you want a `Seq[Seq[String]]` that has 2 elements? Then instead of `flatMap`, use `.map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping,

```
val xs = Seq("spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blu")
val groups = xs.head.split(",|;").map(_.trim).grouped(4)
```

This delivers an iterator of arrays of up to 4 items. The last array contains only 3, the colours.

To see the contents in the iterator,

```
groups.toArray
Array(Array(spring, summer, autumn, winter), 
      Array(red, green, blu))
```

Comment: I try it, but when I want to print it I have:
empty iterator

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you seem to want based on a single element in the sequence and gives you a way to handle the case where you don't have the expected data in the string result from the SQL query. You may need to do some string trimming if that is a requirement.

```
val xs = Seq("spring; summer; autumn; winter, red; green; blu")

val ys = xs.head.split(",") match {
  case Array(seasons, colours) => Array(seasons.split(";"), colours.split(";"))
  case _ => ??? // unexpected case - handle appropriately
}

println(ys.toList.map(_.toList))

// List(List(spring,  summer,  autumn,  winter), List( red,  green,  blu))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to lloydmeta:

```
sequence.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(_.split(";"))
```